# Tailwind is not working on a new laravel project

Tags: html, laravel, tailwind-css

I just installed a clean Laravel project with the Jetstream starter kit, so it also installed Tailwind CSS.

I then tried to use the sample code from Tailwind but it won't show up.

This is my simple test code from the Tailwind docs: (from https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states)

`app.blade.php`: (You can run the code snippet because this is actually what I get in my project)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>

<body class="font-sans antialiased">
    <button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700">
        Hover me
    </button>

</body>

</html>
```

this is the `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    purge: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/js/**/*.vue',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    variants: {
        extend: {
            opacity: ['disabled'],
        },
    },

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
};
```

this is the `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');    
  
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ])
    .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

and this is the `app.css` file:

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` to compile the assets if you didn't already.

Comment: Yes! and also the Tailwind documentation doesn't show the entire tailwind classes that create the elements as seen on their website - so you actually need to copy the entire element to get the real code behind what you see on the screen! (I do "Right click with mouse > Inspect > Copy > Copy element" on Google Chrome for example)

Comment: This really solved my issue. It was difficult to search for this, as only parts of Laravel were not working. Luckily, I found your answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should first run this command `npm run dev` then run `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 1):

If the issue remains after `npm run dev`

update app.blade.php AND guest.blade.php with

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
      <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```